# Should the Stein-Shakarchi Analysis Volumes be Studied in Order?

Tags: self-learning, book-recommendation

I couldn't find this question anywhere else, so just thought I would ask it here. There is a series of 4 analysis books written by Stein and Shakarchi (sometimes called the Princeton Lectures in Analysis), and as I intend to study from them, I was wondering whether it is important or not to learn the material in the order that the books were written:

1. Fourier Analysis
2. Complex Analysis
3. Real Analysis
4. Functional Analysis

For example, is the Fourier analysis in the first volume a prerequisite to understanding the complex analysis in the second volume? Or can one just proceed straight to complex analysis while having just a basic background in real analysis (like Tao or Rudin)? Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, the answer is "they don't _need_ to be studied in order". I've personally read (most of) their Complex Analysis book, though I never read their Fourier Analysis book. They occasionally give examples that assume you've seen some thing from book 1, but I didn't find them distracting and was happy to move on without them. I can't speak for their Real or Functional books, however, as I haven't read them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most math books contain an introduction that outlines the prerequisites. I have only read Vol III, but that one was generally self-contained. I doubt an introductory complex analysis book would require Fourier analysis.  Quoting from the intro to Vol III:

> Despite the substantial connections that exist between the different
> volumes, enough overlapping material has been provided so that each of
> the first three books requires only minimal prerequisites:
> acquaintance with elementary topics in analysis such as limits,
> series, differentiable functions, and Riemann integration, together
> with some exposure to linear algebra.

In my opinion the chief prerequisite is "mathematical maturity", i.e., familiarity with proving stuff.  They may not be so good as an introduction to proof-writing.

Comment: "They may not be so good as an introduction to proof-writing." - absolutely not lol, they expect you to have that very solidly under your belt already

Comment: It's telling that even the first book on Fourier analysis presupposes an understanding of the Riemann integral, so you really have to have taken a first undergrad course in real analysis before embarking on any of the volumes.